# Replace right UIBarButtonItem on Navigation controller with "Done" button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I've looked at lots of articles to help me but could not find the answer...

I would like to replace my right bar button when the keyboard is active with a "Done" button and then replace it back when the editing has finished...

I already have a right bar button which is a segmented control and is setup when the view loads. I am not sure if I can switch the bar button once it is created ?

The following is some screen shots...

[image: Would like to change the Prev / Next Button to a done button when keyboard appears]

Would like to change the Prev / Next Button to a done button when keyboard appears

[image: Screen with Keyboard]

The following is my code that triggers when the keyboard is displayed... The code executes but the button is NOT displayed...

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
// Replace the Right Navigation Button with done button

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                            target:self
                                                                            action:@selector(doneEditing)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;

// Slide up the view

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

CGRect rect = self.view.frame;

// Move the view .... Note need to calculate this based on the size of the keyboard !!

rect.origin.y -= 120.0f;
rect.size.height += 120.f;

self.view.frame = rect;

// Resize the text view .... Note need to calculate this based on screen size !!

CGSize frameSize = self.reviewTextView.frame.size;
CGPoint framePos = self.reviewTextView.frame.origin;
[self.reviewTextView setFrame:CGRectMake(framePos.x, framePos.y, frameSize.width, 200.0f)];

[UIView commitAnimations];

return YES;
}
```

The following is the code segment for setting the prev / next button when the view is loaded

```
    //set up the segmented control and add it to the nav bar rightBartButtonItem

UISegmentedControl *segmentControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"\U000025C0\U0000FE0E Prev", @"Next \U000025B6\U0000FE0E", nil]];
UIBarButtonItem * segmentControlButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentControl];
[segmentControl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
segmentControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 30);
[segmentControl setMomentary:YES];
[segmentControl addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(onSegmentChanged:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = segmentControlButton;
```

Comment: How did you set the prev/next button in the first place?

Comment: Added the code above to show how the Prev / Next Button is setup when the view is loaded.

Comment: Then i don't understand. I'm unable to reproduce the problem. Using your exact same code, it all works fine. The problem must lay somewhere else..

Comment: I think you have just triggered the answer !!! I have the code duplicated !! The code above is part of a view loaded into a scrollview ... I think I need to change the code that handles the scrollview ... will try this later - Please bare with me ...

Comment: Thanks for the support ... You triggered a thought that due to this being a sub-view that I was not executing the code in the right place.... The code has now been placed in the parent view

Comment: Glad of being useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to prompt the system to redraw the bar with the changes, try calling `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setNeedsDisplay]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
if(keyboardIsActive){
UIBarButtonItem *menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                   target:self.revealViewController
                                   action:@selector(revealToggle:)];

    destinationViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but this is a coding error on my part...

The support from User MICANTOX You triggered a thought that I have the correct code but in the wrong place !!! Due to this being a sub-view that I was not executing the code in the right place.... The code has now been placed in the parent view